# File upload viewer component in Yii

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

Is there any component in Yii that can upload and let the user view uploaded file after upload:

I want single extension to handle following files:

jpg, png, gift, mp3, wav, docx, doc, pdf and wmv

I have tried using [XUpload](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/xupload/) but it does not generate previews of the files for PDF, doc and video files after upload.

Any suggestions? I have already wasted hours in searching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's going to be difficult finding a single thing that does all what you ask. 
You'll probably have to split the upload and the view functionality.
After the upload finishes, determine the file type and then ajax-return some kind of preview-url to load.

You'll probably even end up with different viewers that you'll have to support (one for pdf, one for audio, etc). It's highly unlikely that there is a single previewer out there than can handle all formats you mentioned.

Comment: Thank You. 
Yeah you are right. I have already spent hours finding a single extension for that purpose. May be I will have to do as you suggested.

Comment: Note of warning: It might be easier to do a regular upload and redirect to a viewer page than to attempt to do an ajax file upload and view it within the same pageview. You'll probably need an extra plugin that can take care of an ajax post of a form with a file element. It doesn't work out of the box.